# RTC how to add a log file into a build result

Tags: build, rtc, jazz, buildengine

So far I met all preconditions to perform a build, i have 
 - a build user, a build repository workspace
 - a build server with a running build engine
 - a build definition (command line) and a lot of build results...

When my build is running it creates some extra information in a build.log file...

How can I attach that file from the build server to the build result after the build job is done? (well - it should be done at the end of the build job, not after the job is done). The file should be added by the build job and not be added manually...

[image: build file would be here]

i know it should be easy, but honestly - i'm stuck a bit, maybe even ashamed to ask such an trivial question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to attach files to the *RTC Build Result* is by running the respective [LogPublisher Ant Task](http://rb-alm-help01.de.bosch.com:8080/help/topic/com.ibm.team.build.doc/topics/r_logpublisher.html).

You will need to provide an **RTC Build Toolkit**, available for Download from *jazz.net*, and pass it via command line (example below).

```
ant -lib /opt/rtc-build-toolkit/buildsystem/buildtoolkit
```

It will obviously require you to add this command to your build script (or Jenkins if it's the case). Either way, it's much more simple than programatically. RTC API has its tricks. Not fun. :-)

Just in case, IBM provides several other Ant Tasks for publishing stuff, see [here](http://rb-alm-help01.de.bosch.com:8080/help/index.jsp?re=1&topic=/com.ibm.team.build.doc/topics/r_publishbuildresult.html&scope=null).

Comment: wow thank you - i'll take a look immidiately at it! (it's still a pending issue)

Comment: hello rafaelrezend, i've create a totally new Build Definition and try to add a log. but even though i set the checkbock for "include the Jazz buil toolkit" i still get the error "failed to create task or type logPublisher". Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: i think i found out what caused that matter: deep inside the documentation you find how define such tasks, i'll provide this within your answer!

Answer (score 1):

You have **Add File...** button on the right. Please try using it.

Comment: how can i tell my build job to do this for me? - this is the very question?   -   i'll adjust my question... i'll still give a +1 for that very good & obvious answer ^^   thanks for helping....

Answer (score 1):

The only hint that it could be possible to do this programmatically is in
"[Add Log To Build Result](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/62642/add-log-to-build-result)".

> The essence of it is in `com.ibm.team.build.internal.publishing.AbstractContributionPublisher.publish(IBuildResultHandle, BuildStatus, ITeamRepository)`.

This isn't obvious though.

Comment: VonC - YOU again =) how comes you know so much about RTC/Jazz SCM ?!?  i'll take a trial on your approach, i think i will be able to perform such a task, and, if it works i'll let you know as soon as possible!

Comment: i can't promise to do that today, it seems i have to start a small java batch job to perform this - but: it looks like a good idea to me! but as mentioned, i don't think i can do the trial today, it will take some time here.. but i'll let you know how it works!

Comment: Sure, I would be interested to know if it works too. As for my knowledge of RTC, my current mission involves assisting users with it. See my resume on my Stack Overflow profile page.

Comment: i've read your resume already when you helped me out mith 'create multiple checkins' hehe !   i just want to say i'm impressed of how much you know and how much you can help me out here!!! a BIG THANKS already!!!

Comment: just to keep you up to Date VonC - i have created a contribution (a custom log file which can be added to a build result) and it can be added to the 'current build result'... but it's not showing yet, so i'll keep up that path and tell you how it goes... see you soon!

Comment: @MartinFrank great. I look forward reading more about that possible solution.